# Jmockit: how to verify a method was called on a specific instance

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

I am using JMockit 1.15 on Java 1.7.

**I would like to verify that some tested code first creates a new instance of a particular class (*ExampleClass*) and then calls a method on that very instance.**
I tried many ways, using verifications, expectations, @Mocked, @Injectable in many different ways, but I could not succeed.

An Example follows.

**ExampleClass** is a class; I am going to mock it and I want to verify how it is used.

```
public class ExampleClass {

    final double id = Math.random();

    public ExampleClass() {
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("I did something - " + id);
    }

}
```

**ExampleClassUser** contains the logic I want to test.

Note that wrongUsage() builds two instances of ExampleClass but always calls doSomething() on the first one.

```
public class ExampleClassUser {

    public void rightUsage() {
        final ExampleClass exampleClass1 = new ExampleClass();
        exampleClass1.doSomething();

        final ExampleClass exampleClass2 = new ExampleClass();
        exampleClass2.doSomething();
    }

    public void wrongUsage() {
        final ExampleClass exampleClass1 = new ExampleClass();
        exampleClass1.doSomething();

        final ExampleClass exampleClass2 = new ExampleClass();
        exampleClass1.doSomething();
    }

}
```

**ExampleClassUserTest** is the test I would like to build.
It should check that each method call to rightUsage() or wrongUsage()

1. creates a new instance of ExampleClass
2. calls doSomething on that instance
3. creates another instance of ExampleClass
4. calls doSomething on that second instance

The test should succeed when applied to rightUsage() and fail when applied to wrongUsage().

Of course, my test is not able to do that, because it just checks that the new instance are being created and that the two method calls are performed, but **does not check on which instance the method calls are performed".

```
import mockit.FullVerificationsInOrder;
import mockit.Mocked;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


@RunWith(mockit.integration.junit4.JMockit.class)
public class ExampleClassUserTest {

    @Test
    public void testUsage(final @Mocked ExampleClass exampleClass) {

        //new ExampleClassUser().rightUsage();
        new ExampleClassUser().wrongUsage();

        new FullVerificationsInOrder() {{
            new ExampleClass();
            exampleClass.doSomething();

            new ExampleClass();
            exampleClass.doSomething();
        }};

    }

}
```

Comment: The test can be written with JMockit, but it won't look good. I think you should describe the *actual* testing problem you need to solve, rather than showing a contrived example. I bet the real problem will be easier.

Comment: Well, I tried to make it clearer and executable by an ad hoc example, but, as you ask me, I'll report the real case.

Comment: I have a class that represents an ssh call (with constructor `SshCommand(String command, Host targetHost)`) and has an `execute()` method. Many instances of this class are used throughout the tested code. I would like my unit test to check which instances are created and on which instances the `execute()` method is used.

Comment: I saw your example solution below and it was exactly what I had in mind (I just have to wait for the new version release). Why do you say " _it won't look good_" ?

Comment: It wouldn't look good on JMockit 1.16 or older, because the test would have to make use of a `Delegate` object with an `Invocation` parameter so it could get access to the new instance and save it to a field in the test class. JMockit 1.17+ uses an internal "equivalent instance" mapping when matching method expectations to previously matched constructor expectations, so the test gets much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

With JMockit 1.17 or newer, the following version of the test will work (ie, it will fail as expected):

```
@Test
public void testUsage(@Mocked ExampleClass exampleClass)
{
    new ExampleClassUser().wrongUsage();

    new FullVerificationsInOrder() {{
        ExampleClass e1 = new ExampleClass(); // matches first new instance
        e1.doSomething(); // matches only on instances equivalent to "e1"

        // Same as before, now for the second instance.
        ExampleClass e2 = new ExampleClass();
        e2.doSomething(); // fails with a "missing invocation"
    }};
}
```

Comment: Do you think it is the same to write inline, in the verification block, the object creation and the method call (`new ExampleClass().doSomething();`) instead of assigning the new created instance to a variable? (It seems working, but I am not pretty sure it is correct).

Comment: Yes, it's the same; I only used the local variables for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit hard to test methods that instantiate objects, as outside the method you don't have access to the newly created instances. The solution to this would be to use a `Factory` that creates the `ExampleClass` instances, factory that you pass it as a dependency to `ExampleClassUser`. Now you are in control as you can mock the factory to return any objects you need (mocks, custom unit testing objects, etc) and since you have access to those objects you can make assertions on them.

Another approach, if you don't strongly need to make sure the object/method was called, would be to not assert the proper object/method was called, but assert on the effects of those calls. This would have the benefit of decoupling the tests from the method implementation. This approach is feasible only if `doSomething()` has side effects that can be detected without needing to access the objects, and might involve a complex setup.

For example if `doSomething()` returns a prime number and each time is called it returns the next prime number (first call would return 2, second 3, and so on), and the tested method adds the two numbers and returns them (yeah, I know silly example), you can detect if `doSomething()` was called on two different objects, as their sum is 4. If instead `doSomething()` is called on the same object, then the returned result is 5.

Comment: Do you think this is a Jmockit limit or rather a bad testing pattern?

Comment: It's not a jmockit limitation, it's the code that is not testable. Basically since the reference to the created objects are accessible only within the scope of the enclosing method, there's little that can be done from outside the method. Now if you want to test that doSomething() was called on the appropriate object then you either move the object instantiation outside the method, somewhere you (and jmockit) have access, or... I'll add this approach to the answer as it would be helpul for other people that run across this page.